# Nginx error : 19829#0: *24630 "/var/www/vhosts/ is not found (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx

[image][image]When I read my access log I often find some nginx error like the following :

19829#0: *24630 "/var/www/vhosts/studiopsicologiaabruzzo.it/httpdocs/psicologo/Blog/PsicologiaNaturalMente/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)

I have not anymore the directory Blog/PsicologiaNaturalMente/ so I am asking why this error ? And where comes the info about this directory that I have deleted ?
May this error cause some issues in visiting my site ?
Thank and Bye

Comment: That looks like an error log entry. Is there a corresponding access log entry?

Comment: Richard Smith I have uploaded an image.

Comment: "I have not anymore the directory Blog/PsicologiaNaturalMente/ so I am asking why this error ?" Did you *previously* have that directory?

Comment: The image you uploaded is showing a different error to the one in your original question.

Comment: I had before the directory Blog/PsicologiaNaturalMente/ , but I have deleted know. I think to have also some old backlinks to this directory. Perhaps some redirection in the ngsinx directives.

Comment: I have uploaded a new image.. Thanks

Comment: My question is : if the nginx is in error can I loose some visits ?